# Break or merge loops over arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

Let's say I have 3 arrays `image`, `blur` and `out`, all of dimensions  M×N×3.

I want to compute the bilateral gradient of each pixel in the array `image` (current_pixel - (previous_previous + next_pixel) / 2) over x and y dimensions, divide it by some floats, then add the value of the corresponding pixel from the array `blur` and finally put the result into the array `out`.

My question is, in C, what is the most efficient way to do it (regarding the memory access speed and computing efficiency) :

One loop indexing the 3 arrays at once :

```
for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0 ; i < M-1, j < N-1, k < 3 ; i++, j++, k++):
    out[i][j][k] = (2 * image[i][j][k] - image[i+1][j][k] - image[i][j+1][k]) / 2. + lambda * blur[i][j][k]
```

Two loops indexing only two arrays :

```
for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0 ; i < M-1, j < N-1, k < 3 ; i++, j++, k++):
    out[i][j][k] = (2 * image[i][j][k] - image[i+1][j][k] - image[i][j+1][k]) / 2.

for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0 ; i < M-1, j < N-1, k < 3 ; i++, j++, k++):
    out[i][j][k] += lambda * blur[i][j][k]
```

(for readability, I only wrote a simple forward gradient, but the complete formula is given above).

Or is there another faster way ? I'm programming for x86_64 CPUs.

Comment: Looks more like Python than C.

Comment: Generally you want to loop through arrays in a way that takes advantage of spacial locality (sequentially, stride 1) to minimize cache misses and extra memory accesses. I am tempted to recommend the two separate loops since you only access two separate arrays at once, but as sg7 says, compiler optimization might lead to different results. You need to trst both.

Comment: @user3386109, Indeed I'm seasoned in Python and newbie in C, but the syntax doesn't matter much, I wonder about the paradigm.

Comment: The syntax matters quite a bit in C. Specifically, there's no such thing as one loop changing 3 indexes. You need three nested loops (or you need to get the syntax right so it's clear what you're doing), and the order of the three nested loops impacts your performance.

Comment: "*the syntax doesn't matter much*" well ... what you show us makes no sense in C.

Comment: @user3386109 I have explained in words what I try to do. Isn't it possible to use the comma operators in the `for` declaration to avoid nesting loops ?

Comment: `i=0, j=0, k=0` and `i++, j++, k++` will work as expected. But the conditional in the middle is equivalent to `k < 3`. That's because the comma operator evaluates the left expression and discards the result. It then evaluates the right expression and uses that result. With `i=0, j=0, k=0` each assignment is performed, and none of the results are needed, so that works as expected. But with `i < M-1, j < N-1, k < 3`, the expression `i < M-1` has no side effects, and since the result is discarded by the comma operator, that expression is essentially ignored.

Answer (score 1):

One loop indexing the 3 arrays at once will be slightly easier for compiler to optimize. But you can quite likely check it and tested it.

Comment: I tried both approaches in compiled Cython (compiled with GCC), it seems that the single loop is a tad faster. I will try it in pure C.